# Create Custom Look and Feel for a JTabbedPane

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, jtabbedpane

I am trying to create a JTabbedPane that will always fill the top part of the Component with the tabs. Like so:

[image]

And this is how it look now:

[image]

And the code for this part:

```
    JTabbedPane tab = new JTabbedPane();
    tab.addTab("Items", items);
    tab.addTab("Categories", categories);
    setContentPane(tab);
    //Also tried to create a JTabbedPane class and see if i could remove the labels and manually add two buttons to the top but without success.
```

I want the tabs to use up as much space as possible without actually shrinking the content of the panels.
So could anyone tell me how to customize the JTabbedPane, the look and feed or just the tabs themselves in order to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest approach is probably to create your own component:

1. Create a "main" panel that uses a BorderLayout.
2. Create a panel that uses a GridLayout and add your buttons to this panel. Then add this panel to the "main" panel using `BorderLayout.PAGE_START`. Each of these button will display a specific panel when clicked.
3. Create a second panel that uses a `CardLayout`. Add this panel to the "main" panel using `BorderLayout.CENTER`. Each of these panels will represent a tab.

The other option is to look at the `TabbedPaneUI` and find a method that paints each tab and modify the code for your requirement.

Comment: That is kind of what i had in the beginning, two buttons and two panels but the code did not seem very nice so i tried to shorten it. Though this solution seems kinda better.

Comment: why GridLayout and not just BoxLayout on the X_AXIS?

Comment: It worked fine, though i had to add a new parameter to store the title of the button, since when i was calling super(text); for the new button class the size of the button would change.